# Extend class Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to extend the class firebase.firestore.Firestore ?
The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore) say not to call the constructor so

```
ExFirestore extend firebase.firestore.Firestore{
    constructor(){
         super();
    }
}
```

Would be against it.

Comment: I would advise not subclassing at all, since you can't control how the Firestore object is created in the first place.  It's a per-app singleton that's managed by the SDK.

Comment: Can you explain why you are gonna extend Firestore class?

Comment: @Prime just making contact with the feature and exploring implementations. A possible reason could be creating a nonSql interface isolated from the underlying service (I start to see that the solution would be having a reference to the instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this answer as a Community Wiki as it's based on @DougStevenson's comment above.

It is not advisable not to subclass the `firebase.firestore.Firestore` class at all, since you can't control how the Firestore object is created in the first place.

The reason for that is because the Firestore object is a per-app singleton that is managed by the SDK.